# Worse results when using tf.estimator.DNNRegressor vs tf.contrib.learn.DNNRegressor

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am having issues when using the canned `tf.estimator.DNNRegressor` available for Tensorflow. I am getting much worse results at around 3.05 loss with `tf.estimator.DNNRegressor` vs 0.018 loss with the `tf.contrib.learn.DNNRegressor`.

It's important to note that they are running the same code (same features, same epochs, steps, activation_fn=tf.nn.relu, hidden_units, optimizer, etc.)

I would like to know if there are some significant differences between the two regressors. Why am I getting worse results if they are using the same parameters? and How to solve this in order to have similar results?

I saw that the `tf.contrib.learn.DNNRegressor` is being deprecated, so the new estimator implementation should at least have similar results, right?

Thanks in advance for any help or clarification.

Comment: You are probably still missing at least one parameter that is different between the two estimators.

Comment: How many times have you run each estimator? The weights are randomly initialized.

Comment: Yes, my assumption would be that there is one parameter that I need to manually change/adjust on the tf.estimator.DNNRegressor to make it work the same way as tf.contrib.learn.DNNRegressor. Also, I am aware that weights are randomly initialized, that's why I have run the models many times to double check (probably about 50 times). Thanks for your suggestions.